# How to call C function from Matlab that return enum type data?

Tags: c, matlab, dll, enums

I try to work with C DLL for a camera (SDK here https://astronomy-imaging-camera.com/software-drivers) in Matlab 2021b with MinGV compiler.
Functions that have numeric arguments and pointers to it works fine. For example:

```
if not(libisloaded('ASICamera2'))
    loadlibrary('ASICamera2')
end
iCameraID = int32(0); % set camera ID to 0
calllib('ASICamera2','ASIOpenCamera', iCameraID) % Open camera
calllib('ASICamera2','ASIInitCamera', iCameraID) % init camera
piNumberOfControls = libpointer('int32Ptr', iNumberOfControls)
calllib('ASICamera2','ASIGetNumOfControls', iCameraID, piNumberOfControls) % get the number of controls
```

The problem appears when function argument is a pointer to enum variable:

```
ASIGetControlValue
Syntax
ASI_ERROR_CODE ASIGetControlValue (int iCameraID, ASI_CONTROL_TYPE
ControlType, long *plValue, ASI_BOOL *pbAuto)
Usage
get a specific control type's value as currently set for a specific camera ID
Description
int iCameraID camera I D
ASI_CONTROL_TYPE ControlType control type
long *plValue pointer to the current value
ASI_BOOL *pbAuto return whether the control is auto adjusted
```

where

```
typedef enum ASI_BOOL
{
ASI_FALSE =0,
ASI_TRUE
}ASI_BOOL; True or false
```

How can I call such a function?

I tried to call

```
calllib('ASICamera2','ASIGetControlValue', iCameraID, ASI_CONTROL_TYPE.ASI_GAIN, pGain, pGainAuto)
```

with various definitions for pGainAuto using libpointer, but the error appears:

```
Error using calllib
Pointer types must match data type.
```

Comment: An enum is an int.

Comment: Cris Luengo, thank you for the reply. I tried all integer types of matlab: (u)int8, 16, 32 - the error is 'Pointer type must match data type'.